# Measure of inverse image of a monotone function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

I'm studying for my analysis qualifying exam, and came across this question:

> Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a function that is continuous and nondecreasing with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ and define $\phi(t) = \lambda(\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \le t\})$ where $\lambda$ is lebesgue measure.
>
> 1. Is $\phi(t)$ necessarily continuous from the left?
> 2. Is $\phi(t)$ necessarily continuous from the right?
> 3. Do the answer to parts 1 or 2 change if $f$ is strictly increasing?

So far I have that $\phi(t)$ is not necessarily continuous from the left because if $f(x)$ is the Cantor function then $\lim_{t \rightarrow \frac 12^-} \phi(t) = \lambda(\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) < \frac 12\}) = \lambda([0,\frac 13)) = \frac 13,$ but $\phi(\frac 12) = \lambda([0,\frac 23]) = \frac 23$.

For proving that $\phi$ is continuous from the right, I have that

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow y^+} \phi(t) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi\left(y + \frac 1n\right) =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lambda\left(\left\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \le y + \frac 1n\right\}\right) = \lambda\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \le y + \frac 1n\right\}\right) = \lambda\left(\left\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \le y\right\}\right) = \phi(y),
$$

where we can use $\lambda\left(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \le y + \frac 1n\right\}\right) = \lambda\left(\left\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) \le y\right\}\right)$ because it is a monotone decreasing sequence of sets from the monotonicity of $f$.  I think there might be something missing something because I didn't use the continuity of $f$ anywhere.

If $f$ is strictly increasing instead, I think that $\phi$ is continuous from the left as well but I'm not sure how to prove it.  I'm thinking it would be similar to the proof that it's continuous from the right, but then I don't know where you would apply that $f$ is strictly increasing or what prevents you from applying it when $f$ is just monotone non-decreasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should prove first that you have discontinuity at a point $y$ if and only if the set $\{x\in [0,1]:\, f(x)=y\}$ has positive measure. So if $f$ is strictly increasing, then that set will be a singleton and so have measure zero.